# PHP Amazon API Signature does not Match

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, signature

I am trying to get a Signature for the Amazon API. I have tryied many ways, but everything is not working.

This is the output when I load the site:

> SignatureDoesNotMatchThe request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.a0276c00-dab6-4993-bfba-f1c9e431be72

The Link:

http://webservices.amazon.de/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIAPOZFMTWW53XW3A&AssociateTag=myAssociateTag&ItemId=B017M5OTU2&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Images&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2016-09-22T15%3A37%3A01Z&Version=2011-08-01&IdType=ASIN&Signature=t4n0BqQBsSBu8PVLJaWHSVNo4BmDLtWmlv%2Fmaekapbw%3Dh

The Code:

```
function aws_signed_request($region, $params, $public_key, $private_key, $associate_tag=NULL, $version='2011-08-01')
{
    /*
    Copyright (c) 2009-2012 Ulrich Mierendorff

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a
copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"),
to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation
the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense,
and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL
THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
*/

/*
Parameters:
    $region - the Amazon(r) region (ca,com,co.uk,de,fr,co.jp)
    $params - an array of parameters, eg. array("Operation"=>"ItemLookup",
                    "ItemId"=>"B000X9FLKM", "ResponseGroup"=>"Small")
    $public_key - your "Access Key ID"
    $private_key - your "Secret Access Key"
    $version (optional)
*/

// some paramters
$method = 'GET';
$host = 'webservices.amazon.'.$region;
$uri = '/onca/xml';

// additional parameters
$params['Service'] = 'AWSECommerceService';
$params['AWSAccessKeyId'] = $public_key;
// GMT timestamp
$params['Timestamp'] = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
// API version
$params['Version'] = $version;
if ($associate_tag !== NULL) {
    $params['AssociateTag'] = $associate_tag;
}

// sort the parameters
ksort($params);

// create the canonicalized query
$canonicalized_query = array();
foreach ($params as $param=>$value)
{
    $param = str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($param));
    $value = str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($value));
    $canonicalized_query[] = $param.'='.$value;
}
$canonicalized_query = implode('&', $canonicalized_query);

// create the string to sign
$string_to_sign = $method."\n".$host."\n".$uri."\n".$canonicalized_query;

// calculate HMAC with SHA256 and base64-encoding
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $string_to_sign, $private_key, TRUE));

// encode the signature for the request
$signature = str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($signature));

// create request
$request = 'http://'.$host.$uri.'?'.$canonicalized_query.'&IdType=ASIN&Signature='.$signature;

return $request;
}
?>
```

The Request file:

```
    <?php
require('aws_signed_request.php');
  $amazon = aws_signed_request('de',array('Operation'=>'ItemLookup','ItemId'=>'B017M5OTU2', 'ResponseGroup'=>'Images'),"AKIAIAPOZFMTWW53XW3A","OKguH77p2VnCHK5D+6Z4WnEIn18gpKuzoliZZRpe","My Associate Tag");
    echo($amazon);
?>
```

I hope you can help me or have a another resolution!

Greetings

Comment: I'm fairly confident that you need to sign the request with `IdType=ASIN` already included.

Comment: I am a stupid idiot.. I have added this before testing the script and now its work. Thank you!

Comment: You need "ksort($params,SORT_STRING);" instead of simple "ksort($params);". Some requests working with simple ksort, some not.